# Load json url parameters code (javascript modification)

Tags: javascript, json, html

I have this code , it works when I put it in the same file, but I must separate the html from the javascript, now my problem is how can the function know the #r so it can put the data in it?

```
 <button id="charger">GET Data</button>
    <div id="r">Click</div>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#charger').click(function() {
        $.getJSON('url', function(donnees) {
        $('#r').html('<p><b>Name</b> : ' + donnees.name + '</p>');
        $('#r').append('<p><b>Message</b> : ' + donnees.msg + '</p>');
        $('#r').append('<p><b>id</b> : ' + donnees.Type + '</p>');
      });
    });  
  });
</script>
```

and my modification so far is : 
page.html:
...

```
<p class ="submit"><input  type="submit" id="charger" value="OK" onclick="test();"></p>
    <div id="r">Your data : </div>
```

and the js file :

```
function test() {
    $('#charger').click(function() {
       $.getJSON('url', function(donnees) {
            $('#r').html('<p><b>Name</b> : ' + donnees.name + '</p>');
            $('#r').append('<p><b>Message</b> : ' + donnees.msg + '</p>');
            $('#r').append('<p><b>id</b> : ' + donnees.Type + '</p>');
      });
    });  
  }
```

in the console , the function works , but it doesn't show me the data ..

Answer (score 1):

It's because the only thing your `test` function does is adding an event listener to the `click` event of the `#charger` input. Just take your initial code as is and put it in the seperate js file and that should do the trick. Also, make sure that the jQuery script get's loaded **before** your other script.